# I am trying to make some divs responsive

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make some divs responsive.It's a joomla module actually. But it isn't responsive. My template is responsive. I put that module in a position but if resize the screen it gets bigger and it goes outside that position. 
I started with the first div (YJYC container) and I set the width to 100%. This is a good start, becouse I noticed that if I resize the screen, the result is "good". But I have to do this at the other divs, right?.
How should I continue?
Here is the html

```
<div id="YJYSC_container<?php echo $container_poz ?>" style="height:<?php echo $slider_height ?>px; width:<?php echo $slider_width ?>px;">
    <!-- navigator -->
    <div id="navigator_outer" style="height:<?php echo $slider_height ?>px; width:<?php echo  $thumb_width +30 ?>px;">
        <ul id="navigator">
            <?php foreach ($yousclides as $youscslide):?>
            <li class="element" style="height:<?php echo $slider_height / $visibleItems  ?>px">
                <div class="inner" style="width:<?php echo $thumb_width + 30 ?>px;height:<?php echo $slider_height / $visibleItems   ?>px">
                    <div class="inner_over" style="width:<?php echo $thumb_width +30 ?>px;height:<?php echo $slider_height / $visibleItems -12  ?>px">
                        <div class="border_out" style="height:<?php echo $slider_height / $visibleItems -20  ?>px;width:<?php echo $thumb_width + 0 ?>px;">
                            <div class="border_in" style="height:<?php echo $slider_height / $visibleItems -20  ?>px;width:<?php echo $thumb_width + 0 ?>px;">
                                <?php if($youscslide['img_url'] != "") echo $youscslide['img_tumb']; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end of navigator, start slides -->
    <div id="slides" style="height:<?php echo $slider_height ?>px; width:<?php echo $slider_width  ?>px;">
        <?php foreach ($yousclides as $youscslide):?>
        <div class="slide" style="height:<?php echo $slider_height ?>px; width:<?php echo $slider_width  ?>px;"> <a href="<?php echo $youscslide['link'] ?>" title="">
            <?php if($youscslide['img_url'] != "") echo $youscslide['img_out'] ?>
            </a>
            <div class="long_desc" style="width:<?php echo $intro_desc_width ?>;height:<?php echo $intro_desc_height ?>;<?php echo $intro_desc_pozi ?>">
                <h1><a href="<?php echo $youscslide['link'] ?>" title=""><?php echo  $youscslide['title'] ?></a></h1>
                <?php echo $youscslide['intro'] ?> <a href="<?php echo $youscslide['link'] ?>" title="" class="yousc_readon"><?php echo JText::_('YOUSC_READ') ?></a> </div>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use percentages
so if you use 25% for a div inside the 100% div
that means the width would be 25% from the upper div
and it can go beyond

Comment: You don't have to put these on anything else unless you're using fixed widths

Comment: Also take a look at bootstrap, a fully responsive framework. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @ManZzup that's what I am trying to do. I took all the divs from the start and "play" with percentages....

Comment: We can't help you with the code you've provided. Either create a jsfiddle, or you'll have to inspect your page with your browser's developer tools, and navigate through each element to check which one has fixed width, and change it to responsive.

Comment: @AmarSyla what code should I provide? Sorry I don't know much. I'll try to create a jsfiddle.....

Comment: Since you're using Joomla, you will be unable to create a jsfiddle easily, but you can send at least a link of a live demo of your website.

Comment: I think I did it. Here it is. http://jsfiddle.net/gg9mvtrt/

Comment: @AmarSyla The link is here to have a look. http://www.zantepress24.gr/draseis I tried all night long , reading posts, applying edits....with no luck :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    #YJYSC_container, #YJYSC_container_l {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important;
    }

    #YJYSC_container_l #navigator_outer {
          position: relative !important;
          width: 100% !important;
          height: auto !important;
          margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    #YJYSC_container #slides, #YJYSC_container_l #slides {
          width: 100% !important;
    }

    #YJYSC_container #slides div.slide, #YJYSC_container_l #slides div.slide {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
    #YJYSC_container #navigator li.element div.inner, #YJYSC_container_l #navigator li.element div.inner,
    #YJYSC_container #navigator li.element div.inner_over, #YJYSC_container_l #navigator li.element div.inner_over,
    #YJYSC_container_l #navigator li.element div.inner div.inner_over .border_out,
    #YJYSC_container #navigator li.element div.inner div.inner_over .border_in, #YJYSC_container_l #navigator li.element div.inner div.inner_over .border_in,
    #YJYSC_container #navigator li.element div.inner div.inner_over .border_in, #YJYSC_container_l #navigator li.element div.inner div.inner_over .border_in img{
        width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important;
        float: none !important;
    }

    #YJYSC_container #navigator li.element, #YJYSC_container_l #navigator li.element {
        float: left;
        width: 33% !important;
        height: auto !important;
        clear: none !important;
    }

    #YJYSC_container #navigator, #YJYSC_container_l #navigator {
        overflow: auto !important;
    }
}
```

This code triggers on devices with width under 900px. It still needs more work, but responsivity is starting to make sense.

Updated jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gg9mvtrt/1/

Comment: It's a good start my friend. Thank you. I guess I have to do the same with other screens...

Comment: Remember making use of !important, because the script you're using for the slider applies width and height to all elements inline, and you can override those styles only with !important. If the answer helped, please vote up or mark as correct.

Comment: Yes it helped! I am starting to understand what to do next.